# class initialization in java

Tags: java

Why does java allow this

```
public class A {

    private int i;

    public A(int i){

    }

}
```

but not this

```
public class A {

    private final int i;

    public A(int i){ // compile - time error

    }

}
```

What is the difference push the item to the stack when it is **final** ? Why doesn't it understand that A(i) is different than final int i ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable in constructor has nothing to do with final class member the compile time error you are getting is due to final variable is not just initilized .

Try this it will work

```
private final int i=0;
```

**or**

```
class A {

    private final int i;
       public A(int i){
       this.i = i;
    }

}
```

**or**

```
class A {
    private final int i;
    public A(int i) {
    }//constructor over
    {//initilizer block
        i = 10;
    }
}
```

**compiler needs final member to be initialized while it initialize object.**

Comment: I know this but I'm confused with how java push the item to the stack because there is not any difference between calling any method

Comment: @hilal  didn't get your comment , there is nothing to do with stack and method call here

Comment: @hilal, how do you mean? Your compile error comes from the fact that you your `final` member field `i` isn't assigned a value before the instance is constructed.

Comment: @hilal check [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#35962)

Comment: I mean int i;  f(int i){}. but I forget to initialize the final while init.

Comment: @hilal yes you need to initilize final variable check bold line in answer

Answer (score 6):

It will allow the second snippet when you assign a value for `i` in the constructor:

```
public class A {

    private final int i;

    public A(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

}
```

Note that this is how you create [Immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 6):

`final` member fields must be assigned before an instance's constructor finishes.

From [Java Language Specification, 3rd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#35962)

> 8.3.1.2 `final` Fields
>
> A field can be declared `final` (§4.12.4). Both class and instance variables (`static` and non-`static` fields) may be declared `final`.
>   It is a compile-time error if a blank `final` (§4.12.4) class variable is not definitely assigned (§16.8) by a `static` initializer (§8.7) of the class in which it is declared.
>
> **A blank `final` instance variable must be definitely assigned (§16.9) at the end of every constructor (§8.8) of the class in which it is declared; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.**